# Fully Simplifying a Boolean Expression with DeMorgan's Theorem

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, boolean-algebra

The expression I have is \$\overline{(\bar{A}B+\bar{A}C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \$, and I've been asked to simplify it using DeMorgan's Theorems. I've already made a start, which was to discount the double-negation, thus giving \$(AB + A\bar{C})+(BC +\bar{B}\bar{C})\$, but find myself unsure of what further steps I could take to simplify the circuit. Can it be further simplified, or have I done all that can be done to implement the circiut more efficiently?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you handled the "double-negation" correctly?

Comment: I've edited your question (waiting for approval), please make sure I have edited it properly. I did make sure that the overbar above AC or BC were separate because \$\overline{xy} \neq \bar{x}\bar{y}\$, for an example.

Comment: Are we talking about DeMorgan's or Captain Morgan here?  A Few people need to seriously review the theorem rules: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/demorgan.html

Answer (score 1):

\$\overline{(\bar{A}B+\bar{A}C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C})\Leftrightarrow \$

You made a mistake with the first \$\bar{B}\$ and the operator should also be inverted:

\$\\(\overline{\bar{A}B}\cdot\overline{\bar{A}C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow\$

Now you can apply De Morgan's law again

\$\\((\bar{\bar{A}}+\bar{B})\cdot(\bar{\bar{A}}+\bar{C}))+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow\$

\$\\((A+\bar{B})\cdot(A+\bar{C}))+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow\$

\$\\(AA+\bar{B}A+A\bar{C}+\bar{B}\bar{C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow\$

\$\\(A+\bar{B}\bar{C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \Leftrightarrow\$

\$\\A+\bar{B}\bar{C}+BC + \bar{B}\bar{C} \$

To not finish your homework (probably) , you can continue from here.

Comment: @Downvoter: why the downvote?

Comment: Firstly I've not downvoted but, I suspect that someone seeing your answer might be thinking you should use proper latex script. They might think this because the original question was edited some time after you left your answer and it makes your answer (retrospectively) look a little untidy. You have my sympathy because you just copied and pasted the original formula from the "untidy" original question.

Comment: Thanks for that comment, indeed, he changed the layout, so I also updated my answer accordingly (long time ago I used Latex).

Comment: @HarrySvensson You are right (well I saw the incorrect B negation, but the operator should also be inverted) … I will try again (it's also too long ago for me I think).

Comment: I down voted. I noticed the error just before having to run to leave my house. It was all I had time for.

Comment: @Oldfart Thanks for replying … I fixed the error now. (assuming you mean forgetting the inversion, also used the Tex formatting).

Comment: Thank you all so much for your assistance, and the additional resources.

I was hoping that I could ask where !BA + A!C disappears to in the third line from the bottom. Is it to do with the existing !B!C expression alongside our A input?

Comment: I should also mention that, although I appreciate (and am very open to) the correction, I don't understand how I could be mistaken with that first !B operator. On the diagram I've an AND gate taking A and B as input, leading to an inverter, the a XOR gate. Surely that means a bar above AB, no?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the XOR ... a bar above AB means the inversion of the result (A.B).

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thank you very much for your great edit! Really appreciated.

Comment: @user316193 the reason that !BA + A!C can disappear is that A is already +ed (or OR-ed) ... If A is TRUE, A +  !BA + A!C does not matter since TRUE or X or Y will always be TRUE, if A is FALSE, you get FALSE or FALSE or FALSE which is always FALSE, i.e. the result is exactly A.

Comment: @user316193 Here's the math behind that line that I chose to skip: \$\\AA+\bar{B}A+A\bar{C}+\bar{B}\bar{C}\rightarrow\\A(1+\bar{B}+\bar{C})+\bar{B}\bar{C}\rightarrow A+\bar{B}\bar{C} ~~~~\$ If you don't have AA but have A, then just... write AA, it's the same thing. A = AA = A1A1A... . In Boolean the AND is like a 1 bit multiplication, since it can only have two values you get 1*1 and 0*0, which again is 1 and 0. Same thing with 1*1*1*1*1 and 0*1*0*1*0, they still turn into 1 and 0. So just AND a thing by itself, or by the number "1" if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as Michel Keijzers, just a simpler process.

\$\overline{(\bar{A}B+\bar{A}C})+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \$

\$\overline{(\bar{A} (B+C}))+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \$

\$(\bar {\bar{A}} + \overline{(B+C}))+(BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}) \$

\$A + \bar B \bar C + BC + \bar{B}\bar{C}\$